# Google Assistant SDK now unable to answer basic questions

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I was trying to use Google Assistant Service to embed a Google Assistant on my device and it was working very very well. However, after I seemingly changed nothing, it seems that the Google Assistant lost most of its capabilities.

I tried following the instructions for Google Assistant Library (the python one) as well, using a brand new project, and was able to set up the assistant successfully, however, even this unmodified google library is having the same issue. Anything beyond a simple question like "who am I" or "who are you" results in "I'm sorry, I don't know how to deal with that".

It's important to note here (and why this is so weird) that it is actually recognizing what I say. Here's an example of the terminal output from running G. A. Library:

```
   ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {"text": "who won the World Cup"}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {"is_error_response": false}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {"with_follow_on_turn": false}


ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {"text": "who am I"}
ON_RENDER_RESPONSE:
{
  "text": "To get you that information, I'll need your permission. You can give it to me in the Google Assistant settings on your phone. Once that's done, ask me again!",
  "type": 0
}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {"is_error_response": false}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {"with_follow_on_turn": false}
```

As you can see, it recognizes what I say, but doesn't actually recognize basic questions.

Similar questions to "who won the world cup" that do not work that *did* work before include "who is elon musk" or "tell me who won the stanley cup". And again this seems to still happening with a fresh Google Assistant Library install, having made a new project and refollowed the installation instructions.

I guess it could be a google permissions-related thing? Does anyone have any guesses?

Comment: Did you enable activity controls for the user making the query? https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/activity-controls

Comment: I feel... very dumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out activity controls were disabled. After reenabling them, it still did not work so I created a new google account and it worked fine.